# Object coming from the routes is not set to the controller Object

Tags: angularjs, json, html

**View Controller**

This is my view controller, here i am passing the object in state.go

```
$scope.editOrganization = function(organization){   

 console.log(JSON.stringify(organization));

 var OrganizationObj=JSON.stringify(organization);

 $state.go('admin.organization.basic.edit', {myParam: OrganizationObj});

};
```

**Router**

```
.state('admin.organization.basic.edit', {
      url : 'edit/:orgId',
      params: {myParam: null},
      views : {' ' : {
             templateUrl : 'pages/partials/admin/organization/organization.add.html',
             controller : 'EditOrganizationCtrl'
                  }
               }
          })
```

**Edit Controller**

This is my edit controller, here i am getting that object, i am setting to organization object in edit controller. While debugging and in console also i am getting that object. but in page it is not setting, it is printing only empty object. like {"name":"","id":""}

```
console.log("OBJ", $stateParams.myParam);
$scope.organization= $stateParams.myParam;
```

**HTML**

```
{{organization}}
```

Comment: try $scope.organization = angular.copy($stateParams.myParam);

Comment: try  angular.extend($scope.organization, $stateParams.myParam) if u r sure that object is printing in console.

Comment: If i use timeout means, it is working. I hope form is loading after setting the object....
setTimeout(function(){ 
$scope.organization=$stateParams.myParam;
}, 1000);

Comment: Ok, in case , have you tried <span ng-bind="organization"></span> ?

Comment: Yes, i tried. that object is setting before form loading. I think that is reason, it is not showing. After loading only we have to set the object. Then only it will set.

Comment: Angular modal works on two way data binding as if u change value in controller it should automatically reflect in UI if value is changed. i hope ur HTML have an scope of edit controller

Comment: Hi @pari. Use $injector.invoke. Its delay the route change until your object is resolved. Because the controller  expecting that, the object immediately resolved.